# I am confused Relay.QL fragments, Relays' queries and routes?

Tags: relayjs

I am following a relay tutorial and I am confused with this part of the code:

```
exports.Container = Relay.createContainer(ConferenceApp, {

/* 1st id on mock database */
  initialVariables: {
    userToShow: 1
  },
  fragments: {
    user: () => Relay.QL`
/* what is this fragment on 'User'? does this has to be the name on/from the   UserType Schema or this could be anything? */
      fragment on User { 
        name,
        conferences(userToShow: $userToShow) {
          edges {
            node {
              id,
              name,
              description
            },
          },
        },
      }
    `
  },
});

exports.queries = {
  name: 'ConferenceQueries',
  params: {}, // what is params purpose here?
  queries: {
    user: () => Relay.QL`query { user }`   // why do we have this user query when we have the query above?, what is this user field?
  },
}
```

And on the app root, I've read this in docs, I just need to have a strong grasp, I am having OCD with this

```
<Relay.RootContainer
    Component={ConferenceApp.Container}
    route={ConferenceApp.queries} // is this something like react router? :/
    onReadyStateChange={({error}) => { if (error) console.error(error) }} />
```

I put my questions on comments to specifically point out. Would really appreciate explanation on those parts, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok then. Let me try to answer you.

**1. What is this fragment on 'User'?**

Well, in GraphQL, queries declare fields that exist on the root query type. On the other hand, GraphQL fragments declare fields that exist on any arbitrary type. For example, the following fragment fetches the name and conferences for some User.

**2. What is params purpose here?**

Get your own example. If you need to get some particular user, you need to specify the id of the user to be able to get it. So, this is why we have these params.